# How to make a method wait for the Observable#subscribe to be called first before proceeding with the rest of code?

Tags: angular, observable

I have an angular app where I am using a third party chat plugin ng-chat.
To implement its chat adapter I have to override a method

```
getMessageHistory(userId: any): Observable<Message[]>
```

In this method I am calling my service method to get the data from my server

```
 this.userService.getChatHistory
```

and subscribe to it , once the data is available I want to construct the array of messages and return from the overridden method `getMessageHistory`
But for some reason the statements in getMessageHistory after the subscribe call is getting executed before the subscribe's callback are called.
Below is my code

Service method

```
  public getChatHistory(loggedInUserId,selectedUserId){

         let data = {"requestingUserProfileId": loggedInUserId, "targetUserProfileId":selectedUserId};
        return this.http.post(this.apiEndPoint + '/xxx/', data, this.jwt())
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());


    }
```

In my adapter implementation

```
getMessageHistory(userId: any): Observable<Message[]> {
 let msgHistory: Array<Message> =[];
this.userService.getChatHistory(this._loggedInUserId,userId).subscribe(
                  messages => { 
             if(messages ==null || messages.length ==0){
                this.messages = [];
             }
             else{
             console.log("messages retrieved are "+messages);
             this.messages = messages;



            for (var msg of  this.messages) {

                 let tempMsg :Message = new Message();
                 console.log("from id is ",msg.fromId);
                  tempMsg.fromId= msg.fromId;
                  tempMsg.toId= msg.toId;
                  tempMsg.message= msg.messageText;
                  msgHistory.push(tempMsg);

            }

             }});
  console.log("msgHistory array ",msgHistory);  //==> This is getting //executed before the  messages => { in the subscribe above
            return Observable.of(msgHistory);


    }
```

In My output I can see
`msgHistory array  []` being printed before

```
messages retrieved are [object Object],[object Object]
```

So my msgHistory array being returned is always empty.
Is there a way that empty msgHistory is not returned, i.e. code should wait for subscribe call to finish before proceeding with the return statement?

I have also tried putting the logic

```
this.userService.getChatHistory(this._loggedInUserId,userId).subscribe
```

in a separate function and returning it, even then same issue.

Comment: There's a bit of a design problem here... what is `this.messages`? Where is it used? How does that differ to `getMessageHistory()`? @hemu's answer makes sense, but it has code smells that make it hard to understand the stream, but I don't know how to improve that without having more context on what your use case is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that **subscribe is an asynchronous operation**; which means the observable you have subscribed to, should emit values asynchronously. Only one solution I can think of is to convert the Observable sequence into a Promise and put the console.log statement inside the .then() function. You can do it with the **toPromise** function. For more details, check http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toPromise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could you try following code with `first` and `flatMap` operator of `rxjs` :

```
getMessageHistory(userId: any): Observable<Message[]> {
 let msgHistory: Array<Message> =[];
 return this.userService.getChatHistory(this._loggedInUserId,userId)
            .first()
            .map(messages => { 
                if(messages ==null || messages.length ==0){
                    this.messages = [];
                } else {
                    console.log("messages retrieved are "+messages);
                    this.messages = messages;
                    for (var msg of  this.messages) {

                        let tempMsg :Message = new Message();
                        console.log("from id is ",msg.fromId);
                        tempMsg.fromId= msg.fromId;
                        tempMsg.toId= msg.toId;
                        tempMsg.message= msg.messageText;
                        msgHistory.push(tempMsg);

                    }

                }
                return Observable.of(msgHistory);
            });

}
```

Comment: Why map+flatmap of Observable.of(...)? You can let map own `msgHistory` and return that, so you won't need to `flatmap`

Comment: @olivarra1 - Actually that's correct. We can also return Observable.of(..) from map once response processed. Correcting.

Comment: Still this needs to be tested with actual APIs by @TruckDriver.